# Expressing "show me how to ~"

Tags: translation

I want to ask someone (who is older than me) to show me how to wear a Yukata. I'm just not sure how to say it - slightly beyond my level.

> 先週私は浴衣を買いました。
>   Can you please show me how to wear it?

Would it be something like this construction:

見せてくださいませんか。

Thanks.

Comment: A policy of this site is that you should first give it a try because we don't do direct translation request. What is your problem: how to say "how"? how to say "please"?

Comment: I just dont know how to connect the elements of the sentence.
見せてください - show me please/let me see (??)
Really its the "can you..." part, making a request essentially.

Comment: 浴衣の着方を見せて/教えてもらえませんか。You can choose between 教えて and 見せて and you can also replace もらえませんか by a other expressions to show more or less respect to your interlocutor, for example くださいませんか.

Comment: そうですか。ありがとうございます。

Comment: you can also see 着付け instead of 着方

Comment: Hi, welcome to JLSE. You can try using [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/) or [HiNative](https://hinative.com/en-US) which deals with "how do you say this"-type questions. These questions tend to attract close votes on our site unless there is a specific question to be asked about the sentence, or if there are additional elements that prevent it from being translated simply.

Answer (score 3):

For "(Can you) please show me how to wear it(=Yukata)", you could say:

> - (浴衣の*) [着方]{きかた}を[教]{おし}えてください。
>     Please show/tell me how to wear it (a Yukata).
> - (浴衣の*) 着方を教えてくれませんか。
>     Can you show/tell me how to wear it (a Yukata)?
> - (浴衣の*) 着方を教えていただけませんか / 教えてくださいませんか。
>     politer; Could you please show/tell me how to wear it (a Yukata)?

(*「浴衣の」 can be left out in your context.)

Use the verb 教える for "show" in the sense of "explain / give instructions". 
(見せる is more like "show" in the sense of "to cause/allow something to be physically seen".)

Alternatively, you could say:

> - どうやって(浴衣を*)[着]{き}る(の)か、教えていただけませんか / くださいませんか。
>     Could you please show/tell me how I wear (a Yukata)?
> - どうやって(浴衣を*)着ればいいか、教えていただけませんか / くださいませんか。
>     Could you please show/tell me how I should wear (a Yukata)?

(*「浴衣を」 can be left out in your context.)