# How to say "This is how I do [...]"?

Tags: word-requests, sentence

> 私はかんじをべんきょうします。

This literally says "I study kanji".

But I would like to say "*This is how* I study kanji." or "I will *show you how* I study kanji".

Can anyone help with this structure?

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38871/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47234/7810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> これが私の漢字の勉強の仕方です。
>   This is how I study kanji.

In general, 'how to do verb'/'way to do verb' is formed by adding 方 to the masu-stem of the verb, e.g. 作り方 = 'way to make. When you add 方 in this way the whole thing acts like a noun. So "way to make bread" would become パンの作り方.

する verbs are a little different. For some reason you need to add an extra の, so the 'way to study kanji' would be 漢字の勉強のしかた = 漢字の勉強の仕方.

Comment: One way to think about it is that 勉強する isn't really a verb as such, it's short for 勉強をする. So when you have the noun form of する, 仕方, you need the の to join the two nouns 勉強 and 仕方, just as you need it to join the two nouns パン and 作り方.

Comment: @Chocolate In the context where the speaker has already been asked 'How do you study kanji?' do you still need to add 私の? And, is my sentence unnatural regardless. Should I delete it?

Comment: In that context you won't need to add 私は... Your reply will depend on how the question is asked... 例えば...「どうやって漢字を覚えてますか？」「こうやって覚えてます。」/「(XXさんは)漢字はどうやって勉強しますか？・するんですか？」「こういうふうに勉強します。」/「XXさんの漢字の勉強方法は？ / ～の勉強の仕方を教えてください。」「こんなふうに・こういうふうに・こんなやり方で勉強してます。/こんなふうにやってます。」etc... って感じで・・・　ところで You can't delete an accepted answer.. (＾＾)

Answer (score 7):

I would say...

> [私]{わたし}は**こうやって**[漢字]{かんじ}を[勉強]{べんきょう}します。

Example:

> ♪ This is the way we sweep the floor
>   So early in the morning
>   「私たちはこうやって床を掃くのよ　朝早く」

<sub>You could also use 「このように / このようにして」(← sounds a bit more formal)「こういうふうに / こういうふうにして」「こんなふうに / こんなふうにして」</sub>

Answer (score 4):

One way you could say `this is how i study kanji` is:

> 私は**この方法{ほうほう}で**漢字を勉強します

I've bolded the difference between this and your original. Let's analyze how the この方法で works. この means `this`, 方法 means `way/means/method`, and で is a particle indicating the method something is done (among other things). Thus, this literally means `I, with this method, study kanji`. I suppose it's probably closer to `I study kanji this way`.

If you wanted to emphasize `this` you could say:

> これが私の漢字を勉強する方法です

It's fairly similar to https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/7944/user3856370's answer, the only thing of note is that 方法 unlike 方 can be directly attached to 勉強する without a の.